# Read only email archive

Tags: email, thunderbird, archiving

I have a big gmail email database and i want archive it, and use in read only mode. I want to use like thunderbird, but without structure modifying functionality or email deletion possibility, just in read only mode.

This is possible?
How?
Any ide?
Thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is no possibility for gmail to create read only folders/labels so far or set any ACLs on mails/folders - which is the best way to do what you want. With a custom IMAP server, one can use ACLs to allow insertion of new emails to a folder, but denying deletion/alteration of an email on the contrast. And there is an [addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/imap-acl-extension/) for TB to manipulate the ACLs.

I also had in mind to copy/move all the archived emails from gmail to the Local folders, but setting this read-only would need to be done through file system permissions.